# Alternatives to "Hac abierit"

Tags: word-request

In Seneca's *Epistulae morales ad Lucilium* (Letter 3):

> Itaque si proprio illo verbo quasi publico usus es et sic illum amicum vocasti quomodo omnes candidatos 'bonos viros' dicimus, quomodo obvios, si nomen non succurrit, 'dominos' salutamus, **hac abierit.** Sed si ...

> Now if you used this word of ours in the popular sense, and called him "friend" in the same way in which we speak of all candidates for election as "honourable gentlemen," and as we greet all men whom we meet casually, if their names slip us for the moment, with the salutation "my dear sir," – **so be it.** But if ... ([trans](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Moral_letters_to_Lucilius/Letter_3): Richard M. Gummere.)

I was unable to find this phrase anywhere else in corpus, if indeed it captures well the sentiment of the modern English "so be it" (not sure I see exactly how) , I'm looking for other phrases. There is the obvious *fiat* which [L&S has](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=facio%20&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) as "expression of assent, so be it! very good! *fiat, geratur mos tibi"*; [there is also](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=fors&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) *fors fuat pol*. But the later is clearly a wish and the former might be. Here *hac abierit* seems to have the flavor of "Let this discussion end here then /Okay then"  which is little different from the vast *"fiat"*.

I just feel there has to be another succinct way to say it but could not find one (maybe just another verb). If non exists so be it (thought I'm not sure we can even use *hac abierit* here)

Comment: I think *ita est* or something with *sic* is the more normal way to go for that.

Comment: Licet? (Aliquot verba hic addo, ut flagitatur.)